# Mongoose - Is it possible to access object properties with schema path?

Tags: object, path, schema, mongoose

As title. There's an object property `vote` under `ActionSchema`. I want to access `vote.type`, but `path('vote.type')` doesn't work.

```
ActionSchema = new Schema({
  vote: {
    type: String
  }
});

// TypeError: Cannot call method 'enum' of undefined
ActionSchema.path('vote.type').enum(['upvote', 'downvote']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `vote.type` isn't the path, `vote` is. So if you want to modify the `vote` property, then you want to use `ActionSchema.path('vote')`

So to add an enum:

```
ActionSchema.path('vote').enum('upvote', 'downvote');
```

* Note that you don't pass an array of enum values to this function, you pass the values in as multiple arguments. See [the Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-enum) for more details.